# Providing .jad file download link

Tags: iis, download

We are trying to provide a download link to abc.jad file in index.html. abc.jad and index.html are both in the same folder. Following is the link.

```
<a href="abc.jad" type="text/vnd.sun.j2me.app-descriptor">download</a>
```

In addition, we defined the mime type for .jad file in web.config as follows

```
<mimeMap fileExtension=".jad" mimeType="text/vnd.sun.j2me.app-descriptor" />
```

In spite of these, we are still not able to download this file from the web browser. It always gives the error **HTTP Error 404 - File or directory not found**

The server is IIS with .net 2.0

Can you please help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

i know is a little bit late but you are missing these MIME types:

(you have to set these types to your folder on IIS Admin Console)

.cod

application/vnd.rim.cod

.jad

text/vnd.sun.j2me.app-descriptor

.jar

application/java-archive